# Can't add a .egg file to scrapyd addversion.json

Tags: python, django, scrapy, python-3.8, scrapyd

The problem I had is I can't upload my `.egg` file to scrapyd using

> curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/addversion.json -F project=scraper_app -F version=r1 egg=@scraper_app-0.0.1-py3.8.egg

its returning an error message like this

> {"node_name": "Workspace", "status": "error", "message": "b'egg'"}

So I'm using `Django` and `Scrapy` in the same project, and I had this folder structure

```
my_app/
-- apps/  # django apps folder
   -- crawler/ 
      -- __init__.py
      -- admin.py
      -- apps.py
      -- etc..
   -- pages/
      -- __init__.py
      -- admin.py
      -- apps.py
      -- etc..
-- my_app/  # django project folder
   -- __init__.py
   -- asgi.py
   -- settings.py
   -- etc..
-- scraper_app/ # scrapy dir
   -- scraper_app/ # scrapy project folder
      -- spiders/
         -- abc_spider.py
      -- __init__.py
      -- middlewares.py
      -- pipelines.py
      -- settings.py
      -- etc..
   -- scrapy.cfg
-- manage.py
-- scrapyd.conf
-- setup.py  # setuptools for creating the egg file
-- etc..
```

and here is what my `setup.py` looks like

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="scraper_app",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Khrisna Gunanasurya",
    author_email="contact@khrisnagunanasurya.com",
    description="Create egg file from 'scraper_app'",
    packages=find_packages(where=['scraper_app'])
)
```

my `scrapyd.conf` file

```py
[scrapyd]
eggs_dir    = eggs
logs_dir    = logs
logs_to_keep = 5
dbs_dir     = dbs
max_proc    = 0
max_proc_per_cpu = 4
http_port   = 6800
debug       = off
runner      = scrapyd.runner
application = scrapyd.app.application
```

and my `scrapy.cfg` content

```py
[settings]
default = scraper_app.settings

[deploy]
url = http://127.0.0.1:6800/
project = scraper_app
```

So what I want is add an `.egg` file to my `scrapyd/addversion.json` and here is my step by step to achieve what I want:

1. run `py setup.py bdist_egg`
2. `.egg` file being generated in `dist/` folder and its called `scraper_app-0.0.1-py3.8.egg`
3. cd to `dist/` folder
4. run `curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/addversion.json -F project=scraper_app -F version=r1 -F egg=@scraper_app-0.0.1-py3.8.egg`

and then what I got is an error message, if I tried to run the `curl` from the root dirs, and run something like this `curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/addversion.json -F project=scraper_app -F version=r1 -F egg=@dist\scraper_app-0.0.1-py3.8.egg` (im using windows) it'll returning this error

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dist\scraper_app-0.0.1-py3.8.egg

I already tried to googled it but I can't find how to solved this or what wrong step I make here, and I already tried to create the `.egg` file from the `scraper_app` dir directly, so just create an egg file from the `scraper_app` project folder, but its not working as well.

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my project? or what I do wrong in here?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I googled it more, and tried the `scrapyd-client` but there are lots of problem with windows, it doesnt easy to use the `scrapyd-deploy`, but I found a video on youtube that show me what is the correct way to install the `scrapyd-client`.

so here is the correct way to install it.

> Make sure you inside a `virtualenv`, and then install the `scrapyd-client` with `pip install git+https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd.git`. So it doesnt show any error or any difficulties to install it

and then you can just run `scrapyd-deploy` on the scrapy project folder.